# Get two big int in c++ and store them in array

Tags: c++, oop

I want to know if there is a way to + two big int like

```
562159862489621563489 + 51456235896321475268
```

without put them in string in c++

Comment: How are you going to input the numbers?

Comment: Let's see how your "big ints" are implemented first.  You can't do addition on an idea -- let's see the implementation of these big ints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use types like `long long` or `unsigned long long`, but be aware of integer overflows ant that the actual biggest number you can get is platform dependent.

Have a look at

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() << std::endl;
```

If this is not enough maybe it is worth looking at [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html)